# Gnu parallel & pipe

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, shell

I want to send each line of a file to another program's stdin, e.g.

input.txt

```
line1
line2
line3
```

I want to use the gnu parallel like this (i.e. pipe each line as stdin to the more command)

```
cat input.txt | parallel --pipe more
```

But it return

```
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
/bin/bash: -c: option requires an argument
```

What I want is (maybe in different order due to the parallel)

```
line1
line2
line3
```

Anyone got the idea?

Comment: Did you have a chance to go through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
cat input.txt | parallel -N1 --pipe wc
```

Comment: Both not work. (No such file or directory). more is just an example for me to test the command which read from stdin instead of argument. What I want is to parallel every line of input.txt and feed them into a customized program that read from stdin and print the processed output. Is it clear now?

Comment: What does 'parallel --version' give? Are you sure it is GNU Parallel?

Comment: WARNING: YOU ARE USING --tollef. IF THINGS ARE ACTING WEIRD USE --gnu.
GNU parallel 20121122

Comment: Disable --tollef (often it is in /etc/parallel/config) then walk through the tutorial  gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: It is not clear whether your program only only reads a single line or more lines. If we assume your program is 'wc', then this works: 'cat input.txt | parallel --pipe wc' or if you want a single line: 'cat input.txt | parallel -N1 --pipe wc'

Comment: cat input.txt | parallel -N1 --pipe wc is the correct answer, can you edit your answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with ....

```
cat input.txt | xargs -I {} more {}
```

or ...
    cat input.txt | parallel more

Comment: I want to pass as stdin to more rather than argument.